# GUI freezed. When I pressed the CLOSE button I want to send to serial port "1" continuously

Tags: java, user-interface, serial-port, processing

I am working with Processing and Control IP5 library and I have a problem in my code.When I press Close button I want to send to serial port "1" continuously with a 3 seconds delay and when I press Open button I want to send to serial port "2" for another 3 seconds, but after the Close button the GUI freezes and I cannot press any button again.

```
import controlP5.*;
import processing.serial.*;
ControlP5 cp5;
Textlabel myTextlabelA;
String serial_list;                // list of serial ports
int serial_list_index = 0;         // currently selected serial port 
int num_serial_ports = 0;  
Serial serial_port = null;        // the serial port
Button b1,b2;

void setup() {

size(800,600);
noStroke();
 cp5 = new ControlP5(this); 

// get the list of serial ports on the computer
serial_list = Serial.list()[serial_list_index];

// get the number of serial ports in the list
 num_serial_ports = Serial.list().length;

myTextlabelA = cp5.addTextlabel("label")
                .setText("Close-Open")
                .setPosition(430,15)
                .setColorValue(0xffffff00)
                .setFont(createFont("Georgia",20))
                ;

Button b1=cp5.addButton("Close")
 .setValue(128)
 .setPosition(400,50)
 .setSize(40, 20)
 .updateSize()
 ;

 Button b2=cp5.addButton("Open")
 .setValue(128)
 .setPosition(500,50)
 .setSize(40, 20)
 .updateSize()
 ;

  Button bUP=cp5.addButton("^") //Up arrow
 .setValue(128)
 .setPosition(140,10)
 .setSize(40, 20)
 .updateSize()
 ;

 Button bDOWN=cp5.addButton("v") //Down arrow
 .setValue(128)
 .setPosition(140,50)
 .setSize(40, 20)
 .updateSize()
 ;

  Button bCONNECT=cp5.addButton("Connect") //Connect button
 .setValue(128)
 .setPosition(190,10)
 .setSize(100, 25)
 .updateSize()
 ;

 Button bDISCONNECT=cp5.addButton("Disconnect") //Disconnect button
 .setValue(128)
 .setPosition(190,45)
 .setSize(100, 25)
 .updateSize()
 ;

 Button bREFRESH=cp5.addButton("Refresh") //Resresh button
 .setValue(128)
 .setPosition(190,80)
 .setSize(100, 25)
 .updateSize()
 ;    

b1.setColorBackground( color( 255,0,0 ) );    //initial b1 color
b2.setColorBackground( color( 128,0,0 ) );   //initial b2 color
bREFRESH.setColorBackground( color (128,128,0) ); //initial Refresh color
b1.setSwitch(true); //convert button to switch 
b1.setOff(); //set True or False
}
 void draw() {
   background(0);
DrawTextBox("Select Port", serial_list, 10, 10, 120, 60);
}
public void controlEvent(ControlEvent theEvent) {
println("Button Pressed:"+theEvent.getController().getName());

if(theEvent.controller().getName()=="^") 
if (serial_list_index > 0) {
  // move one position up in the list of serial ports
  serial_list_index--;
  serial_list = Serial.list()[serial_list_index];
}

if(theEvent.controller().getName()=="v") 
if (serial_list_index > 0) {
  // move one position up in the list of serial ports
  serial_list_index--;
  serial_list = Serial.list()[serial_list_index];
}

 if(theEvent.controller().getName()=="Connect") 
  if (serial_port == null) {
  // connect to the selected serial port
  serial_port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[serial_list_index], 9600);
  println("Connection Succesfull");
}

if(theEvent.controller().getName()=="Disconnect") 
 if (serial_port != null) {
  // disconnect from the serial port
  serial_port.clear();
  serial_port.stop();
  serial_port = null;
  println("Disonnection Succesfull");
}

if(theEvent.controller().getName()=="Refresh") {
serial_list = Serial.list()[serial_list_index];
num_serial_ports = Serial.list().length;
println("Refresh Succesfull");
}     

if(theEvent.controller().getName()=="Close") 
     if (serial_port != null) {
       while (theEvent.controller().getName()=="Close"){
  // Send 1 to serial port
  serial_port.write(49);
   println("sent 1");
   delay(3000);}
}

if(theEvent.controller().getName()=="Open") 
if (serial_port != null) {
  // Send 2 to serial port
  serial_port.write(50);
   println("sent 2");
}
}
 void DrawTextBox(String title, String str, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
fill(255);
rect(x, y, w, h);
fill(0);
textAlign(LEFT);
textSize(14);
text(title, x + 10, y + 10, w - 20, 20);
textSize(12);  
text(str, x + 10, y + 40, w - 20, h - 10);
}
```

EDIT:So mr @KevinWorkman i came to these: I took the part of the code from `public void controlEvent(ControlEvent theEvent)` and put it in `draw()` so i have this:

```
 void draw() {
 background(0);
 if (mousePressed) {
  timeClicked = millis();
 }
 if (millis() < timeClicked + 1000) {
   // Send 1 to serial port
        serial_port.write(49);
        println("sent 1");
 }

 DrawTextBox("Select Port", serial_list, 10, 10, 120, 60);

 }
```

But when i try to connect GUI is not responding. I think that in `mousePressed()` i will name the event i want, but how to do it?

Comment: Please can you post syntactically-valid and properly formatted code. This is very hard to read.

Comment: Hello. It's syntactically valid. Check that u have processing 2.2.1 and control IP5 2.0.4 library. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're venturing into the world of **threads**. This is a pretty big topic, but I'll try to simplify it for you:

Think of a **thread** as a **worker** that can only do **one thing at a time**.

Processing uses a single thread to draw stuff and to handle user interaction. This is usually a good thing, since it means you can draw stuff based on user interaction.

However, you're calling `delay()` which is telling that thread to wait. **It can't do anything else while it's waiting.** This is why you can't click any buttons, and nothing is drawn to the screen, while it's waiting.

Your best bet is to probably refactor your code so it doesn't rely on the `delay()` function anymore. Try to use the `millis()` function to do your timing instead, that way you aren't waiting on the UI thread.

You could also try to create another thread to do the waiting while the UI thread does its thing, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you know what you're doing.

**Edit**: Here is an example that uses the `millis()` function to display an ellipse for 1 second every time you click:

```
int timeClicked = - 10000;

void draw() {
  if (mousePressed) {
    timeClicked = millis();
  }

  background(0);

  if (millis() < timeClicked + 1000) {
    ellipse(50, 50, 50, 50);
  }
}
```

You'd have to modify your code to use similar logic to perform the delay. Try something and ask another question if you get stuck- don't forget to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello mr @KevinWorkman and thank you for your reply. I am pretty newbie at Processing and Java so can u tell me how to rewrite my code for doing this specific thing? Thank you in advance again!

Comment: Mr @Kevin Workman i'm so confused right now... Could you see my post?

Comment: @lftr Please don't post an answer to get more information- that will probably be deleted by a moderator, since that's not how Stack Overflow works. Either edit your question or post a new one if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You send command from UI Thread. Call your sending functions in other threads.